# Is there any empirical support to "chemical imbalance theory" for mental illness?

Tags: neuroscience, experimental-psychology, psychiatry, psychopharmacology, dsm

Has it been proved by measurement of chemicals in the brain that psychiatric disorders have either their origin or continuance due to chemical imbalance in the brain? I saw the documentary [Diagnostic & Statistical Manual: Psychiatry's Deadliest Scam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFhm-xhQocM) which calls the **chemical imbalance theory** a fraud by people labelled as eminent practitioners of Psychology & Psychiatry. Is there a difference of opinion among experts in this field?

Comment: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/40309/is-depression-caused-by-chemical-imbalances

Comment: And some more related questions on this isle of SE linked from this one https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/18675/relation-of-serotonin-level-and-mood-depression